# How to Bake texture on original UV map?

Tags: uv, texture-baking

I recently watched a BlenderGuru tutorial on baking textures. However it requires to unwrap an object to create a new UV map. Is  there a way for me to bake it to the original UV map without making a new one?

Comment: Did you tried to use the "original" UV map as input for your bake-target texture? Didn't it give you problems? Could you show what have you done so far and the issued you faced?

Comment: Just plug your texture to the existing UV map, instead of the new one